# How to get the Row count for only Specified Range of columns in WorkSheet using ClosedXMl

Tags: c#, asp.net, closedxml

I have a worksheet and one column of work sheet has more number of rows and remaining columns has different number of rows. I had a requirement like need to get the rowcount of those columns only not the irrelevant column. I had used the below code to get the rowcount but it is Counting by adding the rows in columns with the rows in irrelevant column.

For Example if I use the below code for the For the worksheet shown in image I am getting 6 but I need to get the 3.

```
int RowCount = workSheet.Rows().Count();
```

See the below image:

[image]

Comment: int RowCount = workSheet.Range("A2:k2").RowsUsed().Count();

Comment: This is the way to get worksheet range count i got it

Comment: Correct. Add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the Count of Specified Rows we Can use the below code

```
int RowCount = workSheet.Range("A2:k2").RowsUsed().Count();
```